# Magento2 rewrite _prepareCollection method

Tags: magento2, overrides, grid

I want to override the **_prepareCollection** method but not working I am using **preference** to override the method, In the same class of another method except *_prepareCollection*  is going to successfully overridden.

Please help on the above issue.Any references and suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have got the answer from Magento core module.

We can override by the following code

**Replace**

```
//return parent::_prepareColumns();
```

**To**

```
return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended::_prepareCollection();
```

It's work for me